# Function becomes volatile

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function fire1(){
            $("#btn").click(function(){
                unbind();
                window.alert("First Fire...");
            });
        }

        function fire2(){
            $("#btn").click(function(){
                unbind();
                window.alert("Second Fire...");
            });
        }

        function fire3(){
            $("#btn").click(function(){
                unbind();
                window.alert("Third Fire...");
            });
        }

        function unbind(){
            $("#btn").unbind("click");
        }
    </script>
    <button id="btn">
        <h1>Select a button below to fire an action</h1>
    </button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="fire1()">
        1st Fire
    </button>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button onclick="fire2()">
        2nd Fire
    </button>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button onclick="fire3()">
        3rd Fire
    </button>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
</body>
<style>
</style>
</html>
```

The code above will change the click method of `$("#btn")` dynamically by clicking the 3 buttons under it. It works only for the first click. When you click it for the second time, nothing happens. It seems like the fuction within click method becomes **volatile**. Can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you unbind your event on the click...

```
function fire1(){
    unbind();
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        window.alert("First Fire...");
    });
}
```

Placing the unbind before will remove click actions and then set the new click event. What you were doing is remove all click events on button click, hence removing the event action for the second click.

If you want to avoid playing with events and just change the behavior of a button, you can call a named function in the event handler, and change it according to the other button clicks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myClickHandler = function(){};
    $('btn').click(function(){myClickHandler();});

    function fire1(){
        myClickHandler = function(){
            window.alert("First Fire...");
        };
    }
    function fire2(){
        myClickHandler = function(){
            window.alert("Second Fire...");
        };
    }

    function fire3(){
        myClickHandler = function(){
            window.alert("Third Fire...");
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: @ Salketer how to remove previously bind event, if I remove `unbind();` `select button works but it trigger previously events `

Comment: You need to unbind events if you do not want them to trigger again... But if you prefer, you could set the click event to trigger a named function, and the buttons could change that function directly instead of playing with events...

Comment: Is there a way to change the click method of the button without using unbind?

Comment: @ Salketer that's what I was talking about vote up from me :)